# Working with difficult people and processes that don't work

Tags: work-experience, stress, teamwork

I work with software development, **I'm trainee for about 5 months**. Nowadays many things worry me in the team (composed by me, my leader and another developer):
 1. We don't work with deadlines and dates of delivery or with forecasts
 2. There is no communication on the team and I just **don't know what everyone is doing**
 3. There are bugs of another person, which send me to correct (even when I'm overwhelmed with so much work) and it's usually a stupid bug.

But what worries me most is the relationship with the other developer, already tried to do `rapport`. This person does gossip in the workplace, sends me work without the permission of my leader (he has made ​​it clear for me to say no to anyone who asks for me to do something without the permission of it) and this developer has called me to talk in private in which he said loudly "was extremely annoying with my attitude" in front of the entire company. I felt disrespected and without any desire to work.

**What should I do?** It is coming time to change jobs? My leader tells more than it does, if I talk to him I'm afraid that the mood in the team getting worse. I'm just a stupid trainee while that person which I have problems is hired by the company. I'm also scared by the way work be "molded" to work well (in meetings with the manager they read the [agile manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) but I just sit and do the codes that tell me to do).

Comment: No, you need to talk to your manager if you are getting bad attitude from another person in your team.  That is what your manager is for.  If the other person cannot behave in a professional way, then it needs to be escalated.

Comment: Oh, and how is your work managed?  How do you know what you have to do and by when?  It sounds like there are some systemic issues.  Again, this should be raised with your manager if you feel undirected.  There is no point suffering in silence.  If you don't speak out, how will anyone know how you feel?

Comment: First I must talk to my manager or the team leader? The leader sends there to do, ask how it should be done and I do (some things can take days), if I have any questions I ask during the process, then he joins what I did to what is in production and sends me something else to do.

Comment: Isn't something like "that should last an entire day to complete" and no evaluation of my progress

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming that they were one and the same given the size of your team.  Who do you report to?  Your manager or the team leader?  That's the person you need to talk to.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you are deailing with improper task assign management and also some people who have a bad attitude.

You should meet with the person who assigns your daily tasks. From your post, I think that may be your team leader. Also you should clarify with your team leader if you need to work on tasks assigned by anyone OR assigned by only your team leader? If he informs you that it is only from them, then every task should come through him first.  He can then decide to whom he should assign each task.

Once you discuss the above issue which your team leader, and if he starts to do proper task assignments then your issue should be resolved.

Comment: @Jane - Thanks a lot for correcting grammar..I am learning so many things by this.. Thanks again...